# Track git cloned project

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I cloned a project from github to my existing project and push it to bitbucket.

It looks like this now:

[image]

That `socketio_runserver` part is the problem.

How can I make it "regular"?

I tried to delete `.git` folder inside it. Did not help

Comment: did you clone it in as a subtree or submodule?

Comment: I just did `git clone ...` ! Was I supposed to do something else? @JeffPuckettII